# disable direct access to route in symfony2

Tags: symfony

I have created a symfony2 webpage with a form in a "/new" route. The user posts the input to controller, the controller renders "/create" and If successfully, the final route "/thankyou" is called and a thank you page appears.

I want to disable direct access to /thankyou route that will be accessible only by successful /create POST. This works for /create (why?) but not for /thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add some conditions in your "/Thankyou" action based on referer information:

```
$request->headers->get('referer');
```

Or you could use some extra parameters in url as @Florian said.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `requirements: _method: POST` to the route will at least limit the access to a POST operation.

But I'm not sure how you could achieve that only a POST from a specific site is accepted. Maybe using a special token that is passed on as parameter that you check for in the controller could do the trick.

Comment: Show some code of your routes, controllers, and whatever else might be involved. We can't fix things we can't see.